# How to get <a> value and pass it to API URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a web api that returns `IEnumerable` result, on top of it there is jquery ajax call that retrieves data and present it in a table for example

```
<table>
    <tr>
          <td><a class="btn-link" id="value.ID">ID<a/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>Gender</td>
    </tr>
```

What I want to do is to redirect the user when they click tge anchor tag `<a/>` 
to http://localhost:1234/page.html?ID=1234

I have tried to search in many articles but nothing is specific to what am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to simply redirect the user upon clicking the button, you can use, window.location to perform this like so:

window.location.href = "url-here";

In your case you can use jQuery to listen for the button click on the button, instead of using the id attribute for the ID that you've retrieved I would use a data attribute as shown below :

```
<td><a class="btn-link" id="value.ID" data-id="value.ID">ID<a/></td>
```

then in your jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-link', function(){
    window.location.href="http://localhost:1234/page.html?ID=" + $(this).data('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Thatcoderguy
that gave me a very good idea about am going to struct my page